two times as little/much as - acceptable

Jack earns two times as much as I do.
Jack earns two times as little as I do.

I am not sure that they are correct. Can you shed some light on the issue?

"two times as much" is valid and sensible. Like, "Jack earns two times as much as I do." If you earn 1000, Jack earns 2000.
I've heard people say "two times as small" or "twice as little", but I think it's very ambiguous. If you say "This stick is twice as small as that stick" ... what does that mean? If the second stick has length 10 (whatever units), what is the length of the first stick? Maybe "twice as small" means the same as "half as big", so if that stick is 10, then this stick is 5. But it's not at all clear.

Where does anyone say 'two times'? It's twice (2x) or half (0.5x). My daughter aged 17 weighs twice as much as my son aged 6. My brother weighs half as much as my sister.

So, how to convey the idea of sentence 2?

Michael Harvey, if it's 5 not 2 what would you say?

@user1425 - five times. For two times we say 'twice'; more than two: we say the number followed by 'times' - three times, ten times, on hundred times...

@user1425 - Jack earns half what I do.

But it's illogical to acknowledge that "twice as much as" is correct but "twice as little as" is wrong.

@user1425 Why? By what rule?

@MichaelHarvey "Twice" is a perfectly good word ... but "two times" is also perfectly good. There's often more than one way to say something.

Jay on what rule do you base your assumption that there must be a rule?

@user1425 On the rule that language follows rules. Because if it didn't, then how could we possibly understand each other? So if there's no rule, on what grounds or basis do you say that we can't declare one meaningful and the other not? Just your whim?

Where did you see the rule that language follows rules? Who established this rule and when? Nobody. What you mean is logic but not a rule.

https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/rules.php, https://basicenglishspeaking.com/basic-english-grammar-rules/, https://www.bing.com/videos/riverview/relatedvideo?&q=grammar+rules&qpvt=grammar+rules&mid=95CF2C8228604439B94995CF2C8228604439B949&&FORM=VRDGAR, etc. But regardless, if it is your position that there is no such thing as a "rule" in language, then what rule are you invoking to say that "twice as little" is correct? You say you think it's "logical"? I say it's not. Where does that get us?

Give me the rule that says that "twice as much as" is correct.
